# Where should I put the subscriptions for MessageCenter in my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I saw some examples where people had placed them in the page constructor. They then unsubscribe in the OnDisappearing().

I have my pages ViewModel send messages and these are then picked up in the back end page C#.  But the problem for me is that my page gets constructed once, I then do this to go to other pages:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new VersionPage())
```

and my subscriptions are lost.

Would appreciate some advice on how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are subscribed on Page1 and you want to navigate to Page2 then, in Page2 you want to call send messaging?

What I would do in this case, I would have boolean value that can be set so that on ondisappearing of Page1, it does not unsubscribe.

I personally dont like using messaging center..

What I would do instead because Page 1 or Page1's viewmodel would be responsible for creation of the Page 2, while creation, I would bind an event to disappearing of Page2 to do something for Page1 when Page2 have finished with something or if it required to do something while Page2 still the mainpage, then create a custom event and bind event to that, so that in Page2, you can invoke that event when you needed..

You can unbind all the event on disappearing of page2 for cleaning up memory loss which is I think its much cleaner in a way of managing and garbaging when not needed.

Comment: Can I ask, what were your concerns with MessagingCenter?

Comment: As you know, subscription and unsubscription is done within the appearing and disappearing of a page usually. This is already a limitation for me as I also faced similar problem as yours, where I needed the messaging subscription to last long as I need and not limited within the subscribed page to be the top stack of navigation and require to unsubscribe when needed, but cannot do this properly. Its really what the project required to do, but my experience, for enterprise app, I never use messagingcenter and I didnt have to force myself to use it.

Comment: The boolean solution i suggested is also just a work around, not a solution. What happens if the app is a masterdetail page, user navigates to Page2 with Page1 still subscribed and wait to invoke disappearing so it can unsubscribe. If user decides to open the slide menu and navigate to totally different page, What happens to the subscribed message? Still subscribed.... It will alway be subscribed because it has never invoked disappearing..And there is no way to check who is subscribed to what...imagine you implement this for lot of pages, how are you going to clean up those subscribed?